# Comment form on custom page template

Tags: custom-post-types, comment-form

I have created a custom page template, but I don't know how to add the WordPress comment form to my `<body>` tag.
I tried to include the following in my `template.php` file in the body tag, but the form won't show up:

```
<?php $comments_args = array('label_submit' => __( 'Send', 'textdomain' ), 'title_reply' => __( 'Write a Reply or Comment', 'textdomain' ), 'comment_notes_after' => '',
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
);

comment_form( $comments_args ); ?>
```

I am using the child theme of twenty seventeen themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display default Wordpress comment form then you need to call `comments_template()` in your template. Make sure that `comment_status` should be `open` for the particular post that you want to display the comment form.

```
<?php
comments_template();
?>
```

Read more here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/

Comment: Thank. Actually my code was correct. But that comment_status=open setting was missing

Comment: Soo your code wasn't correct then :P